# The qrcode generated result page not open

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

W/native  (29858): W0000 00:00:1693997505.755634   31475 abi_method_util.h:33] not supported: TfLiteInterpreterGetTensor: TF Lite in Google Play services has stable ABI version 1.11.0 which is less than the required version 1.13.0.

//this is error show in my flutter app

In my App,  when i am opening QR scanner , when the scanning is done it will go to the result page but when i open the camera this error will show and also after the scanning process the result is not showing.

Comment: Apparently support for version 1.13.0 is still in preview at TensorFlow. See updates here: https://github.com/juliansteenbakker/mobile_scanner/issues/836

Answer (score -1):

You need to update your plugin for scanning qr-code